# pip not downloading any package

Tags: python, pip, chef-infra

I have a linux machine with python set up by the chef cookbook "python".

From a while pip is not trying to download any package from internet.

For instance, if I type

```
pip install argh
```

I get

```
Collecting argh
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement argh
  No distributions at all found for argh
```

Where can I start looking for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

try updating your pip.
pip install --upgrade pip
It should help.

Comment: I had already tried that, after reading another discussion, with the same result:  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages     No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: installing it again (whithout uninstalling) did the job https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 0):

The `python` cookbook is deprecated and presumed broken as stated in the readme, use the `poise-python` cookbook and the `python_package` resource that comes with it.